# Как изменить вывод результатов поиска на стандартный Woo?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Добавил поиск в меню Woocommerce следующим кодом:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_search_box', 10, 2);
function add_search_box($items, $args) {
ob_start();
get_search_form();
$searchform = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$items .= '<li class = "my_search">' . $searchform . '</li>';
return $items;
}
```

Все работает, ищет по товарам, но результаты поиска выводятся в формате записей (posts) Wordpress, подскажите как сделать чтобы вывод был стандартный, как список в любой категории товаров?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В корне вашей темы есть файл `search.php`. Если нет, создайте его. Он отвечает за вывод результатов поиска.

Его надо стилизовать в том же виде, как и файл `/wp-content/themes/ваша-тема/woocommerce/archive-product.php`. Если такого файла у вас нет, возьмите за основу файл `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/archive-product.php`.

Но учтите, что в результаты поиска попадут не только товары WooCommerce, но и другие записи, содержащие строку поиска.

Comment: благодарю! выводит уже как надо, но весь интерфейс на странице результатов поиска перекорежило

Comment: если быть точнее не выводиться ничего кроме результатов, и цвет фона другой

Comment: стоп, неужели к нему еще и нужно подключить стили? или сам файл добавить в какой то список со стилями? search.php создал сам и скопировал туда содержимое archive-product.php

Comment: Стили не надо, все стили есть. Надо разбираться с версткой. Я дал общую идею, ее допиливать надо. Так в лоб, предсказать сложно, какая модификация понадобится.

Comment: понял, спасибо.